# How do I find out how long a socket is in CLOSE_WAIT?

Tags: tcp, netstat

I have a server relatively with a high number of sockets in CLOSE_WAIT

I want to know the age of each socket, to know if it's a real problem (sockets not getting closed) or that the sockets are getting closed, but new sockets are getting into CLOSE_WAIT

Comment: `ss -o state close_wait` might be helpful.

Comment: This is similar to the -o in netstat. but it doesn't give time for CLOSE_WAIT sockets